# SQLAlchemy find IDs from a list that don't exist in a table

Tags: database, sqlalchemy

I have a table with some records(every record has an id - primary key). Now I need to select all ids from specified list/set that don't exist in the table. I am using postgres database and sqlalchemy as ORM. Please suggest have to perform such query.

Answer (score 0):

May not be efficient for a very large set, but straightforward flow for demonstration:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
missing_from_table = []
for id in my_list:
    result = session.query(Model.id).get(id)  # result is a tuple
    if not result:
        missing_from_table.append(id)

print(f'The following ids are not in the table: {missing_from_table}')
```

Another option would be:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
all_ids = [r.id for r in session.query(Model.id).all()]
missing_from_table = [id for id in my_list if id not in all_ids]
```

Comment: This is like extracting the data and then filtering on that. I am intreseted in the query to perform the mentioned operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that operates completely in the database. It bypasses the ORM, but still utilizes SQLAlchemy's conveniences for the session and object mapping.

```
from sqlalchemy import text

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
query = text("""
    SELECT array_agg(id) 
    FROM unnest(:my_list) id 
    WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            id 
        FROM 
            insert-table-name-here
    )
""")

# Belows assumes session is a defined SQLAlchemy database session

missing_ids = session.execute(query, {'my_list': my_list}).scalar()
print(f'The following ids from my_list are missing in table: {missing_ids}')
```

Answer (score 0):

This option uses SQLAlchemy and is very efficient.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import Values, select, column
new_items_values = Values(column("id"), name="new_items").data(
    items_ids
)
query = (
    select(new_items_values.c.id)
    .outerjoin(
        Model,
        Model.id == new_items_values.c.id,
    )
    .where(Model.id == None)
)
# assumes `session` is already defined
missing_ids = set(
    session.execute(
        query,
        {"items_ids": items_ids},
    )
    or []
) # a list of unary tuples, e.g. [('id1',), ('id4',)]
```

This generates SQL like this:

```
select new_items.id
from (
  values ('id1'),('id2'),('id3'), ('id4')
) as new_items(id)
left join model on model.id = new_items.id
where model.id is null;
```

(I compared this to @Matt Graham's solution below, using `WHERE id NOT IN`; this solution takes 20ms; the other one took literal minutes on my database.)

Answer (score 0):

A combination of SQLAlchemy's [`Query.distinct()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.distinct) functionality and set operations makes for something both readable and efficient.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from typing import Set
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# an Engine, which the Session will use for connection
# resources, typically in module scope
engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@localhost/")

# a sessionmaker(), also in the same scope as the engine
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

# declarative base class
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class TableOne(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(String(50))

# Query TableOne using SQLAlchemy Session
table_ids_set: Set[int] = set()
with Session() as session:
    table_ids: List[TableOne] = session.query(TableOne.id).distinct().all()
    for row in table_ids:
        table_ids_set.add(row.id)
    # closes the session

# Your list of IDs you want to ID if they're in TableOne
my_search_ids: Set[int] = {1, 3,4225, 27}
missing_ids: Set[int] = my_search_ids.difference(table_ids_set)
print(f"IDs missing from the table: {missing_ids}")
```